# Rearrange pre-existing physical form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have been doing research for a while now, but cannot find anything anywhere. Here is what I am looking to do. Right now, using javascript, I have a button that creates text fields within a div.

```
var i = 1;
function addbox() {
if (i <= 25) {  // max number of textboxes
$('#services').append("<div id='services"+[i]+"'><input type=text placeholder='Additional Service "+[i]+"' name='service[]' maxlength=255 required=required></div>");

i++;
}
else {
alert ("No more services possible")
}
}
```

This being said, I would like the user to easily be able to rearrange the created text fields by dragging them around.

For example, switch the order from:

```
<input name="text1">
<input name="text2">
```

to

```
<input name="text2">
<input name="text1">
```

Also, it would be nice to be able to easily remove the text field. Any assistance would be great!

Comment: use jquery drag and drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jQuery UI Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)?

Extra letters so my answer can be posted.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It is exactly what I need. I figured I would need jQuery but I couldn't find much of anything. Thanks again!

Comment: Any suggestions how to pull up an option menu to change value when double clicking on the text field?